# Stripe doesn't send e-mail when Checkout.js is used

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a requirement to send e-mail receipts when Stripe payment is used.  The e-mails do not go to the customers.

We are using https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js and in the e-mail settings are configured correctly:

[image]

The JavaScript invoking client side Stripe is here:

```
stripeHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: "{{stripe_key}}",
      image: '/static/img/framework/logo.png',
      token: function(token) {
        $("#stripe_token").val(token.id);
        $("#payment_form").submit()
      }
    });

    stripeHandler.open({
      name: 'My Company Inc.',
      description: "{{order_description|escapejs}}",
      email: "{{ order.user.email }}",
      amount: parseInt(parseFloat($('#total_cost').text) * 100)
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you collect card details via Stripe Checkout, Stripe sends you a card token back with an id like this `tok_XXX`.

Getting the card token is only the first step in the process of handling a payment. You then need to send that token to your server where you use the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) to create a charge and receive a payment or you save the card on a customer using the Create Customer [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

In both cases, Stripe doesn't know the email address of the customer and it's not taken from the token. You have to explicitly send it to the API if you want that email address to be used.

If you create a customer then you'd pass it in the `email` parameter on creation. That email would then be used to send email receipts to that customer whenever you charge their saved card.

If you create a charge immediately without creating a customer first then you have to explicitly tell Stripe to send the email receipt to that address. This is done by passing the `receipt_email` parameter in the API as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-receipt_email).

The last issue with your code is that, even though Stripe sends you the customer's email address back in the `token` callback you're not using it in the code. This means that once the token reaches your server you don't have the email address anymore and your code must simply be ignoring the empty value.

You'll want to change your handler to do something like this:

```
stripeHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: "{{stripe_key}}",
  image: '/static/img/framework/logo.png',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#stripe_token").val(token.id);
    $("#stripe_email").val(token.email);
    $("#payment_form").submit()
  }
});
```

This assumes that your form already has a second hidden input field with the id `stripe_email` where to set the email. You can see a full example with PHP [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78626a38c4b4cb6932af).

Another solution would be to call the Retrieve Token [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token) server-side based on the token id to get the email in the `email` property otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized I hadn't set my server side code to trigger the email. Stripe has some instructions listed at [Automatically send receipts using the API](https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard/receipts#automatically-send-receipts-using-the-api).

In my case, I hadn't set the **receipt_email** parameter. I'm using PHP so my code looks like this:

```
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$emailR = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 30000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Awesome Widget",
  "receipt_email" => $emailR,
  "metadata" => array("Email" => $emailR)
));
```